# Android tcp socket can not receive data

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to work with sockets in android programming, sending to the server works fine but i have problems with receiving a string from the server.

the socket is connected, but if the server is sending a string the android app only prints out: java.io.BufferedReader@418daee0

i dont know what that mean..is it an error or something like that?

this is my code:
Maybe someone could help me a little bit to get that work.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Client extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;


    private static final int SERVERPORT = 2000;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.1";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      



        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }


    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {


                InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String test = br.toString();

                TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.received);
                message.setText(test);

                //in.close();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do is read from the `BufferedReader`.  Currently you are just printing the `br` object.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null) {
   System.out.println (line);
}
```

as per the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) `readLine` will return null if the end of the stream has been reached

Comment: Hi and thanks for Helping me, i changed the code like you wrote but now it displays nothing....i think i have an mistake anywhere in my code, i will try to geht it work.

Answer (score 1):

**problem:**

```
String test = br.toString();
```

You are basically referencing the memory location in string form of the `br` object thus printing the memory location in your `TextView`. What you need to do is to read the inputStream from the socket connection of the server from your `BufferedReader` object.

**solution:**

```
String test = br.readLine();
```

The `readLine` method will wait for the response of the server from the `InputStream` where the socket is connected. Now the above will only get one line of response from the server if the server sends multiple line then you put it in a while loop.

Comment: ... and, in addition, you are going to get an error when you try to touch a View object from the background thread.